# Why doesn't my memory-profiler Memory usage changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to know the actual memory usage of my function. Can someone explain it why if the Memory usage does change and why if the Memory usage doesn't change?

I've tried to follow this link : https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/ and tried with the decorator.

```
import time
import random
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile()
def insertion():
    arr  = []
    for x in range(0,50):
        arr.append(random.randint(0,100))
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        key = arr[i]
        j = i-1
        while j >=0 and key < arr[j] :
                arr[j+1] = arr[j]
                arr[j] = key
                j -= 1
    return arr

print("Sorted :", insertion())
```

I expect the output for every line should be different, well not all, but at least there's an increment. While what I've got only constant Memory usage.

Comment: Please post how you are calling this code as well

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer sure